# Font Awesome Pro in Nativescript

Tags: css, nativescript

I'm developing a cross-platform app with Nativescript and I started   using Font Awesome Free for the icons. 
In order to do that I included the ttf files in the fonts folder and I defined the following classes in the main css file:

```css
.far {
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free", fa-regular-400;
    font-weight: 400; 
}

.fab {
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Brands", fa-brands-400;
    font-weight: 400; 
}

.fas {
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free", fa-solid-900;
    font-weight: 900; 
}
```

So far everything works fine and I can insert the free icons by their Unicode in the text field and assigning the class far, fab or fas to the widget.

Here is an example:

```html
<Button value="4" row="1" col="4" text="&#xf3ed;" class="fas navbar-item" tap="onMenuItemTap"></Button>
```

I tried to to the same with Fontawesome Pro, adding the otf files in the Fonts folder and defining the following classes, but it doesn't work.

```css
.far {
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Pro", fa-regular-400;
    font-weight: 400; 
}

.fab {
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Brands", fa-brands-400;
    font-weight: 400; 
}

.fas {
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Pro", fa-solid-900;
    font-weight: 900; 
}

.fal {
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Pro", fa-light-300;
    font-weight: 300; 
}
```

Could you please help me with that? I contacted the FA support but so far they haven't been able to help me.

Comment: if the Free is working and not the Pro it would be difficult to help since we cannot test or access the files

Comment: I understand, is there anything I can do by my side?

Answer (score 0):

At this point NativeScript cannot support multiple weights of the same font name.

See https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/5920 -- the current solution is to manually rename the fonts internal name (using a font editor) so it has a different name.  So then your CSS looks like this (i.e. the font-families have updated names)

```
.far {
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Pro", fa-regular-400;
    font-weight: 400; 
}

.fas {
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Pro Solid", fa-solid-900;
    font-weight: 900; 
}

.fal {
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Pro Light", fa-light-300;
    font-weight: 300; 
}
```

One small note; if you are only using a couple characters from each of these fonts files it is much better to copy all these characters into your own font file.  Bundling 4 large font files increases the size of your app a decent amount.

Comment: What you're suggesting is exactly what I'm looking to do.  How does one copy characters from multiple source font files to create a new font file?

Comment: There are several websites that allow you to do this; like http://fontello.com/ is one that I've used several times.